# Combining an Time / Date Array to convert to UNIX TIME

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

So I have a form for creating scheduled dates.
Title, Subject, bla bla...
But then, I have a jQuery Date picker, that lets the user pick a date off a calendar.
The jQuery date picker only formats for human dates
I want to store them in UNIX TIME.
So I have this Calendar, for the YEAR, MONTH, DAY...
Then I have a standard drop down for the hour,  1:00 PM, 1:30 PM Etc...

The post print_r($_POST);  looks like this,

```
[time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5:00 PM
        [1] => 1:00 PM
        [2] => 8:00 PM
    )

[date] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2014-05-08
        [1] => 2014-04-04
        [2] => 2014-03-28
    )
```

I found strtotime();  for converting, human time / date into UNIX TIME, however...
How do I get array [0] from time, and date to combine and be a combined string.
There might be only 1 date, or 8 dates?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through your POST data and combine times:

```
foreach($_POST['date'] as $i => $date) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($date.' '.$_POST['time'][$i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($_POST['date']); // assuming both date and time have same amount of values

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $time = strtotime($_POST['date'][$i] . ' ' . $_POST['time'][$i]);
    // do what you want with the time here
    // Example: put all timestamps in an array.
    $timestamps[] = $time;
}
```